# How to use variable with \ in sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a strings file that I want to replace with sed command.

String in the file :

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="xyz.config" />
    <BundleResource Include="Settings.txt" />
    <BundleResource Include="Resources\Base.lproj\Localizable.strings" /> <BundleResource Include="Resources\Base.lproj\InfoPlist.strings" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Below is my command:

```
CONTENT="<BundleResource Include="Resources\Base.lproj\Localizable.strings" /><BundleResource Include="Resources\Base.lproj\InfoPlist.strings" /><BundleResource Include="Resources\es.lproj\Localizable.strings" /><BundleResource Include="Resources\es.lproj\Infoplist.strings" />"

sed -i "s|\.*<BundleResource Include=\"Resources\\Base.lproj\\.*|${CONTENT}|g"
```

but when I use above sed command, it didn't replace it. Do you have any idea why? Did I did wrong with my sed command?

My end result that I want is:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="xyz.config" />
    <BundleResource Include="Settings.txt" />
    <BundleResource Include="Resources\Base.lproj\Localizable.strings" /> 
    <BundleResource Include="Resources\Base.lproj\InfoPlist.strings" /> 
    <BundleResource Include="Resources\es.lproj\Localizable.strings" /> 
    <BundleResource Include="Resources\es.lproj\Infoplist.strings" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `sed`; use a command designed to work with XML, like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: What's the downvote for? -- the question was well formulated, and included an example.   It follows the 'How To Ask'

Comment: @Jon had explained the reason to use command designed to work with XML below. Using `sed` is really painful in case of XML

Comment: @chepner the reason I am not using xml is because the file is not xml file, it is csproj file.

Comment: A [csproj file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5dy88c2e.aspx) *is* an XML file.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with `bash` and `sed` backslash quoting. If you try

```
sed -i "s|\.*<BundleResource Include=\"Resources\\\\Base.lproj\\\\.*|${CONTENT}|g"
```

it should do what you want. Both `bash` and `sed` are collapsing backslahes, so you need four!

Also, you've used double quotes when assigning a string containing double quotes to `CONTENT`, which won't do what you want. Try single quotes:

```
CONTENT='<BundleResource Include="Resources\Base.lproj\Localizable.strings" /><BundleResource Include="Resources\Base.lproj\InfoPlist.strings" /><BundleResource Include="Resources\es.lproj\Localizable.strings" /><BundleResource Include="Resources\es.lproj\Infoplist.strings" />'
```

That said, as a commenter has pointed out, you'd be better off using a proper XML tool rather than `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

As chepner mentioned, you should likely use an xml tool to edit this rather than SED, however, if you wanted to use SED, you likely want something like this:

```
sed "s|<BundleResource Include=\"Resources\\\\Base.lproj\\\\[^>]*>|${CONTENT}|g" < tmp.txt
```

I replaced the `.*`'s, as those can be problematic.   The second `.*` is replaced with `[^>]>`, so it only matches/replaces until the next `>` character.   I also double escaped the `\` characters.